# How to change modal dialog box title dynamically in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to change my modal dialog box title according to the database value. Following is my code to load modal dialog box.

```
page.replace_html 'show_event', :partial => 'show_event'

page<< "$j ('#show_event_dialog').dialog({
    title: '',
    modal: true,
    width: 500,
    close: function(event, ui) { $j ('#show_event_dialog').dialog('destroy') }

}); "
```

I pass event id with link and now I want to change the title as event name. But how can I retrieve database value(event.name) into this js.rjs file? plz can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know rjs well, but every instance variable defined in your controller action should be available to your renderer. try to find your @event in your controller action, and then use string interpolation :

```
page<< "$j ('#show_event_dialog').dialog({
    title: '#{@event.name}',
    modal: true,
    width: 500,
    close: function(event, ui) { $j ('#show_event_dialog').dialog('destroy') }
```